# Accessing Master Page Control From Button Click event of Content Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to change the text property of a label control(lblCustomerLogin) in master page at the click event of a command button (btnLogin) in Content page

I have tried this:

```
Public Property LoginCustomerName () as string
Get
return lblcustomerlogin.text
End Get
Set(ByVal value as string)
lblcustomerlogin.text=value
End set
End Property
```

Then I have added this to content page:

```
  <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Masterpage.master" %>
```

And in content page button click event code behind, i have done this:

```
 master.LoginCustomerName ="Test"
```

I have also tried:

```
dim LabelCustomerLogin as label=  Directcast(master.findcontrol("lblcustomerlogin",label)
LabelCustomerLogin.text ="Test"
```

The problem is the label control(lblCustomerLogin) in masterpage does Not get the new Text value at the button click. But when I move the code(master.logincustomername="test") to load event of the content page, it works. How do i get this to work in button click event.

Answer (score 0):

Directive @MasterType is needed, you added well. The next step is adding the following code to your master page's code behind:

```
public String Customer_Name
{
    get{}
    set
    {
        lblcustomerlogin.Text = value;   
    }
}
```

And in your content page:

```
this.Master.Customer_Name = "myNewValue";
```

P.S. Sorry for example on C#. Hope you can convert it into vb.net.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: this is same thing I have done already, i can't tell why its not working. My site is Ajax enabled anyway, I dont know if that is the reason

Comment: On debug i discovered the lblcustomerlogin text property was actually changing to the new value; but was loosing  it due to a redirect to a another page ( which also uses the same master page). The task is now how to make lblcustomerlogin keep the new value, no matter the content page i navigate to.

Comment: Save this Value into the Session. In another page, if Session's value is not null or empty, set the MasterPage's label's value from this Session